# Permission to play music using MediaPlayer class

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

I would like to let user play his own music library in my game via bult in player. And since im using MediaPlayer class i need to get permision for that to pass the certification. What is the right way to use `MediaPlayer.GameHasControl` property? When i start playing song from  `MediaLibrary` from my built in game player, `MediaPlayer.GameHasControl` becomes false. So i should make sure only once on load that game has control and they can play\pause any song from `MediaLibrary`? Or in some other specific way?

```
    public void GetMediaPlayerControl()
    {
    bool canPlay;
     if (!MediaPlayer.GameHasControl)
     {
         //show window with confirmation that change canPlay to true\false
     }
     if (canPlay)
        {
            MediaPlayer.Play();
        }
    }
```

Is it valid solution to pass certification?